# Cache build folder during gitlab CI build

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a remote server where I serve my project via Nginx. I am using Gitlab CI to automatize my deploy process and I have ran into a problem.  **When I push my commits to the master branch the gitlab-runner run nicely but the problem is that it removes my React build folder** (it is ok, as I have put it into the .gitignore), but because it always removes my build folder my Nginx could not serve any files until the build finish, and a new build folder creaeted. **Is is there any solution for this problem? It would be nice if I could cache my build file until the build process finish.** I attached my gitlab.ci.yml. Thank's in advance!

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
variables:
    GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"
build-step:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - docker image prune -f
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml build
deploy-step:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

Comment: Gitlab ci has [cache directives](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache) you can use. You can find this page typing "gitlab ci cache" in a search engine, where the result should also show a more global documentation page about [best practices](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) for using it.

Comment: I have read about the cache and artifacts from the documentation, but the problem is that before the runner could save the folder, the gitlab delete it during the cloning.

Comment: which executor are you using?

Comment: Shell executor which I'am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to use git fetch and to disable git clean when your deploy job starts. Here are links for the variables to do this:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-clean-flags

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-strategy

It would look something like this:

```
deploy-step:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
    GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

This should make GitLab use `git fetch` instead of `git clone`, and to not run any `git clean ...` commands. The build artifacts from your previous run should then not be removed.

There are some problems with this though. If something goes wrong with a build, you might end up in a situation where you will have to manually log into the server where the runner is to fix it. The reason that GitLab uses `git clean` is to prevent these types of problems.

A more proper solution is to use nginx to have a sort of dubble buffer. You can have two different build folders, change the config in nginx, and then send a signal to nginx to reload the config. nginx will then make sure to gracefully switch to the new version of your application, without any interruptions. Here is a link to someone that has done this:

https://syshero.org/2016-06-09-zero-downtime-deployments-using-nginx/

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it was really useful!